# What song is used in this video?

Tags: music, cowboy-bebop

I've tried using a song finder app to no avail. What is the song used on [this site](http://www.seeyouspacecowboy.com). Is it a song used in Cowboy Bebop? Or just some random song overlaid with Spike's picture?

Answer (score 6):

It's titled "Space Lion", and can be found on the [1st Cowboy Bebop OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/19089), track #7.

Here's a Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKnVaDwUg5s.